# How to get my code to continue to code until "0" is entered

Tags: java

hello I am having trouble with this.

Let keys 8, 4, 2, and 6 be north, west, south, and east respectively. Whenever a user selects one of these options output You moved direction where direction is the appropriate direction. If the user enters zero, which is also a menu option, exit.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
    System.out.println("[8] North");
    System.out.println("[4] West");
    System.out.println("[2] South");
    System.out.println("[6] East");
    System.out.println("[0] Exit");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();



    while (input == 8)
    {
        System.out.println("You moved north.");
        System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
        System.out.println("[8] North");
        System.out.println("[4] West");
        System.out.println("[2] South");
        System.out.println("[6] East");
        System.out.println("[0] Exit");
        input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }


    while (input == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("You moved west.");
        System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
        System.out.println("[8] North");
        System.out.println("[4] West");
        System.out.println("[2] South");
        System.out.println("[6] East");
        System.out.println("[0] Exit");
        input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    while (input == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("You moved south.");
        System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
        System.out.println("[8] North");
        System.out.println("[4] West");
        System.out.println("[2] South");
        System.out.println("[6] East");
        System.out.println("[0] Exit");

        input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    while  (input == 6)
    {
        System.out.println("You moved east.");
        System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
        System.out.println("[8] North");
        System.out.println("[4] West");
        System.out.println("[2] South");
        System.out.println("[6] East");
        System.out.println("[0] Exit");

        input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll want to do a while (input != 0) and inside there do if-statements instead of the while() statements you have now.

Comment: Use only one while loop withcondition input != 0. The differentiate the output depending on your input.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Just one point, we are not your homework completers, Your question however was quite nicely formatted so it wasnt that bad, I would refer you back to your programming teacher or the books Review what the difference is between loops and decision branches (for, while) and (if ,switch) You are using a loop as a decision branch, A usual input processor will get the input then check if the exit option has been entered then check for the other options, and then loop for the next input entry

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
        System.out.println("[8] North");
        System.out.println("[4] West");
        System.out.println("[2] South");
        System.out.println("[6] East");
        System.out.println("[0] Exit"); 
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch(input)
        {
            case 8:
            System.out.println("You moved north.");
            break;
            case 4:
            System.out.println("You moved west.");
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println("You moved south.");
            break;
            case 6:
            System.out.println("You moved east.");
            break;
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As to why your code fails to run here is what is happening:

When you run the code it runs from the top to bottom (first line to last line)

Since you are checking the condition in the loop once you leave that loop it just moves on to the next while loop never coming back to the one it just left.

So once you are past that while (input==8) it does not check for it again.

So after you enter 6 your program has reached its final loop which when fails exits the program

Hope you understood that. Feel free to ask if you don't.

Comment: I think that what he wants is an explanation of why his code behaves the way it does. Let him solve him by himself.

Comment: @Malt added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While you're reading 8's, your code is stuck in the `while (input==8)` loop.
Then once the 6 arrives, it exits that loop and goes into the `while (input==6)` loop. At this point any digit except for 6 will exit that loop and terminate the program.

What you probably want instead is to replace the large number of small loops with a single one that keeps asking the user for his input, and printing the result of his choice. Something like:

```
do{
   //display menu
   //read user's choice
   //react to user's choice
}while(input != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of how a `while` loop actually works. It will continue to repeat itself as long as a certain condition is `true`.

So in your first loop, `while (input == 8)`, if the user selects something other than `8`, the loop exits and your code continues.

But then you hit another loop, looking for another `input` value.  This means you start a loop for each possible entry.

Instead, you should have just one loop that keeps asking the user for input **until** they enter `0`.  Then, inside that loop, since we know they've entered something other than 0, perform some `if` statements to figure out what they entered:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
    System.out.println("[8] North");
    System.out.println("[4] West");
    System.out.println("[2] South");
    System.out.println("[6] East");
    System.out.println("[0] Exit");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (input != 0) {

        if (input == 8) {
            System.out.println("You moved North!");
        }

        if (input == 4) {
            System.out.println("You moved West!");
        }

        // Etc

        // Get input from the user each time the loop repeats
        input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    // The user selected 0 and the loop exits
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve this:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Demo {


    private static void inputDirection() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
        System.out.println("[8] North");
        System.out.println("[4] West");
        System.out.println("[2] South");
        System.out.println("[6] East");
        System.out.println("[0] Exit");
        System.out.print("Select Your Path Number :\t"); // \t this mean tab space
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();
        checkNumber(input);
    }

    private static void selectedDirection(String path) {
        System.out.println(path);
    }

//    logic is here
    private static void checkNumber(int number) {
        if (number == 8) {
            selectedDirection("You moved NORTH..!");
            inputDirection();
        }
        if (number == 4) {
            selectedDirection("You moved WEST..!");
            inputDirection();
        }
        if (number == 6) {
            selectedDirection("You moved EAST..!");
            inputDirection();
        }
        if (number == 2) {
            selectedDirection("You moved SOUTH..!");
            inputDirection();
        }
        if (number == 0) {
            selectedDirection("You are Exited..!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        inputDirection();
    }
}
```

**inputDirection() method**

- scan your input number.
- show your message.
- decreasing the boilerplate of the code.
- next input value.

**selectedDirection(String path) method**

- show the direction.

**checkNumber(int number) method**

- the logic according to user input values.

Also, try to decrease your code repeating(boilerplate). Happy coding.